# Show hide content in List item in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing WP8.1 app in that I need to show some content with show/hide functionality. First 2 lines will be displayed and once clicking on that item the remaining content should expanded and display. How we can achieve this in WP8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show or hide you have to go for binding.

And to expand the content, have your DataTemplate as StackPanel and set the  Height property of TextBlock (through binding) with the value that is needed to display two lines.

And on tap of the item, just get the selectedItem instance and Increase the height property or set to auto

To know about binding see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/cc278072(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, it's worked. Now when I click on the other item the previous item should be collapsed. How we can do that?

Comment: reset the height of the previously selected item to Minimum Height, and do the above for the newly selected one. If you need, add some animations to it.

Comment: Can u tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use visibility and collapsed 
like that

```
     myimage. visibility =visibility.visible;
```

you can control with this way